# importing a project into eclipse using egit

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, git, egit

I am trying to import [this project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase) into eclipse using the egit plugin.  I have been using [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html) to learn how.  But the problem is figuring out what to enter into the dialog box within eclipse.  Neither of the links above provide adequate information about that.  I am including a picture of the eclipse dialog box below.  Can anyone show me what to put into each input field in the dialog box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do

1. Right-click Project Explorer and select Import > Import...
2. Select Git/Projects from Git. Click `next`. Select URI and `next`.
3. Enter `https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase.git` (the git link) into the URI text field. Click `next` twice.
4. Select a directory and click `next`.
5. Select `Import as general project`. Click `next`.
6. Give it a project name. Click `Finish`.
7. Right-click the new project, select `Configure -> Convert to Maven project`
8. Right-click the project, select `Run As -> Run on Server`

I've tried this and it works on Juno with Tomcat 7.0.22.

Comment: I tried similar steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668593/importing-an-eclipse-project-from-file-system-then-running-on-server but seem to be encountering some obstacles.  Do you have a way of fixing the problem at this linked posting?