# importing an eclipse project from file system, then running on server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to do the spring security tutorial  [at this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html).

In the section entitled **"Running the Tutorial application without Spring Security"**, I took the following steps (adjusted for differences between the current version and the version that was in use when the tutorial was written):

```
1.) I downloaded the latest release of the Spring Security Distribution,   
2.) found and unzipped a war file in the dist directory called spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.1.2.RELEASE.war  
3.) Renamed the resulting folder spring-security-tutorial  
4.) Created a general project in eclipse called spring-security-tutorial  
5.) Imported all of the contents of the unzipped spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.1.2.RELEASE.war  
6.) Right clicked on the project in eclipse and selected configure...convert to maven project  
7.) Then right clicked on the project and clicked run as...
```

But there was no "run on server" option.  (I had chosen a general project instead of a Dynamic Web Project in hopes of preserving the file structure of the application to be imported)

I then started to repeat the process, but creating a Dynamic Web Project instead of a general project, and eclipse wants me to select the "src folders on build path".  The file structure of the web application has 8 .class files in subfolders of WEB-INF, and I am not able to locate any .java files.

What steps can I take in order to download this and run it in eclipse on the server?  With the ability to edit the classes?

I have read that I can select a .class file in eclipse and it will open the bytecode in the editor, so I imagine I can convert the class files to java files easily enough.  But doing that within a general project triggers the error message that the class is not part of the classpath, so we need to get it in a working web project that can be run on the tomcat server from within eclipse first, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `war` file is a Web application ARchive (basically a zip). It is meant to contain a web application's compiled class files and resources (properties files, jsps, css, html, js, etc.). It a package that can be used by an application server (or servlet container) like Tomcat. Except through a Decompiler, you will not have access to the source code from the compiled `.class` files.

I doubt you can run this on Eclipse's Tomcat instances. Instead go to your Tomcat installation. Mine is at `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22`. Rename the `war` to something simple like `security.war` and place it inside the `webapps` folder, ie. `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\webapps\security.war`. Go to `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\bin` and execute the `startup.bat` Windows batch file. This script sets up the classpath and launches a Java application containing all the applications in `webapps`. You can see the startup logs in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\logs\catalina.out` (as you would normally in Eclipse console).

You can then go to `localhost:8080/security` to hit the application. Replace `8080` with whatever port you're configured on. `security` is the same name as the `war` file. When Tomcat starts (based on a config parameter) it will extract the `war` into a package directory under `webapps` with the same name.

You can play around with configuration settings. Some of the important ones are [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

You can shutdown Tomcat by running the `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\bin\shutdown.bat` Batch file script. You'll have to do this and restart if you change something in the application (ex. the web.xml or a properties file).

I think the tutorial you linked was meant more for trying security settings than actually changing the source code. I'm sure there are other samples online for Spring security, I just don't know them.

Comment: Thank for this.  +1 for trying to help.  I copied the war to the webappsfolder, renamed it, then went into the bin folder, but there is no startup.bat.  I believe I have tomcat 7.0.42.  I am on Windows 7.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When I try to start tomcat through service.msc, I get a message saying windows cannot start tomcat as a service.  I think that has something to do with the way that eclipse is set up to run on server.  Next, I started another app using eclipse's run-in server, then tried http://localhost:8080/security to try to run security.war, but got a 404 error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @CodeMed Ignore Eclipse completely for now. Your tomcat installation should have a `bin` folder with a `startup.bat` program (are you on Windows?). If it doesn't, go to the official website and reinstall it.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling tomcat screwed up my eclipse tomcat runtime references.  At first, eclipse through an error when I tried to run another app using run on server.  So I deleted the server and tried to install another server, but the server name box is now greyed out in the new server dialog box in eclipse.  In other workspaces, the old server reference is still available, but all my code is in this workspace.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @CodeMed When you create a new server, there's a link to `Add...` a server runtime environment, ie. select a Tomcat installation.

Comment: Yes.  And the server name input box is greyed out in the resulting dialog box.

Comment: @CodeMed Just `Browse...` to your new installation.

Comment: In order to have any chance of accessing that, I had to go into another workspace and import the project, because the current workspace has greyed everything out for tomcat 7.  Now that I am in server view in a different workspace, what to I do to get the dialog box to which you are referring?

Comment: @codeMed Right-click the empty space in `Servers` view, select `New > Server`. In the `New Server` dialog, click `Add...`. This will open `New Server Runtime Environment` dialog. You can either `Download and Install` some version from the net or `Browse...` to your own installation. You then select a name if you want and pick a JRE. Click `Finish` twice.

Comment: Yes, I did that.  And the server name input field in the resulting dialog box is greyed out when tomcat 7 is indicated as the server type.  Also, clicking to download and install does not result in any options for tomcat 7; all the server download options are from other providers.  This happened after I simply clicked on the current tomcat 7 installation in eclipse server view and deleted the tomcat 7 instance in hopes of preparing to reinstall a new instance with the new runtime.

Comment: Window-->Preferences-->Server-->Runtime Environments reset eclipse's knowledge of the location, so that the server name is no longer greyed out, and I can run on server again now.